# How to label the names on x-axis and also change names accordingly in ad-hoc filters in grafana elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

[Here if i want to change the name of others to something else. how must I do in grafana. my datasource is elasticsearc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk1Um.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Go on value mappings on right side where there is option to choose and make settings in visualization. change the value mappings accordingly by writing the value which is originally shown for the bars of bar graph and with the text you want to show on the graph